# Minor issue regarding reputation and badge

Tags: bug, reputation

I should be on 123/150 for legendary.

[image]

Rep got to 200 and I saw the counter go to 123/150. Lost 15 due to pilot6 ( :-) ) removing an accepted answer and saw it go back to 122/150.

The 2 blank lines should have gotten me back to a daily rep of 200.

---

https://askubuntu.com/reputation shows 2016-07-25 rep +200  = 130918

Comment: Sounds like a bug...

Comment: I am sorry that I took the precious points ;-) But the solution really does not work. I can award a bounty if there is a working solution. I am thinking of it, but it looks to be very complex and awkward to do.

Comment: @Pilot6 eh. That is so not the point here ;-)

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but I remember from way back, that sometimes rep calculations can mess up. You can manually refresh them by going to the following link: `http://askubuntu.com/reputation`. (There used to be a button at the end that you can click once a day, but I think it's automatic now.)

Comment: oh I remember that one yes :D